Guarantor for 60-day Indonesia C1 tourism visa?
While applying on the official Indonesian immigration site for a tourism  visa to stay in Bali for 6 weeks, I saw an option for a 60-day visa. The "Document Requirement" looked easy:

Passport...
A recent color photograph.
Proof of living expenses at least US$ 2,000( the round-trip flight alone will cost that).

No mention of any guarantee latter.
But when I clicked the Apply button, I got this popup in broken English:

This Visa can be apply via Guarantor, please contact your guarantor to appy this Visa!.


Bali.com has a page about this C1/C2 visa (formerly known as 211A) but it doesn't say anything about a guarantor.  Their visa intermediary service page subtly implies that you need a guarantor for the C2 (business) visa:

For C2 & C6 Guarantor and Bank Statement will be included in the service

So what's the deal here, and why is this so confusing?
The "Explore visa options" official site says this about the C1 visa (only in Indonesian, 'cuz translation is harddd nowadays):

Single Trip Visit Visa 60 Days (2 Months), can be extended.
Cost

60 Day One Time Visit Visa Rp. 2,000,000/person
One-Time Visit Visa for 60 Day Tours Special for IDR 1,500,000/person
180 Day One Trip Visit Visa for IDR 6,000,000/person


Requirements:

valid travel documents that are valid for at least 6 months;
proof of living expenses while in Indonesian territory; And
Recent color photograph.




The official Indonesian government web page for the C1 visa lists the same document requirements (nothing about a guarantor) and adds,

The visa validity period is 90 days from issuance. If it is not used after this time period, foreigners must apply for a new visa to enter Indonesia.


Processing Time Four working days after visa payment is received [whether applying online or in person]


I am pretty sure the Indonesian authorities couldn't care less how much you pay for your flight. You need proof that you will (probably) spend at least 2000$ living expenses during your stay in Indonesia.

@Axel: my point is that someone able to pay $2k to come to Indoesia probably has more than $2k allocated for their stay in Indonesia. Anyway, other could enter from Singapore for under $100, so it's a legit question. The most ridiculous proof of funds requirement I've seen was for South Africa - they wanted a STAMPED bank statement showing you had at least the equivalent of 3000 South African Rand - US$165.

I decided to ignore that ridiculous pop-up and go ahead with the application myself.
After registering, I had to enter all my personal data again (except for my "mothers[sic] name", which I have no idea how they'll check because it's not on any documents I had submitted).
After submitting the return flight PDF and a 3-month bank statement PDF, the page displayed "Waiting for payment", without any clear payment instructions. Somewhere in an (unnecessary) "invoice" there was a link to a service called "Simponi". Their page was fully in Indonesian, but that's another question.
So it seems you can apply for the 60-day C1 visa yourself. You "just" need to figure out how to pay the application fee in this "amazingly stupid system".
UPDATE1: you can also extend the 60-day C1 visa online during the last 15 days of its validity. If you try to extend before that, you're greeting with another confusing and unprofessional error:

UPDATE2: I applied online for a visa extension as soon as that was possible (15-14 days before expiration). The process was supposed to take "5 working days".
FIFTEEN working days later, my extension was still "Waiting verification", my "staypermit" had expired, and I was in limbo. Another expat told me that this is how things work, and I should pay a visa agent.
Indeed, after I paid balivisas 1M IDR, I got my extension within 2 business days. I didn't have to submit any additional documents. I have no idea what "verification"s Imigrasi was allegedly performing for 15 business days.

Dan. How did you manage to register for C1 Visa account? I've tried at least 30 times - with different pictures (even took professional pictures), used different browsers, different email addresses, every time with same result - nothing. Thank you

Assuming you have a passport which is eligible, the cheapest and easiest way to proceed with a stay in Indonesia of between 30 and 60 days is to apply for the 30-day visa on arrival (or the "e-visa on arrival", which is paid for in advance from home and will let you skip some lines at the border). No guarantor of any sort is required for this, and the application is online or in person at the airport; in neither case would you need the services of any sort of intermediary. Then, you can extend your stay for another 30 days before the first entry permit expires.
This sort of visa extension can be done only once, but the process is usually available online and quite easy to do. If you have any trouble, there are all kinds of visa agents in touristy parts of Indonesia who can (for a fee) help you further.

I've just learned that 9 million passports/visas have been leaked from the Indonesian government database following a ransomware attack in June.
I'd rather wait in line at the airport and hope for less exposure, than send my passport data online to this Mickey Mouse operation.

@DanDascalescu The leaked database contained information about "foreigners entering Indonesia", so the way you get your visa doesn't seem relevant.

@DanDascalescu but I think the e-VOA is extendable online whereas the VOA is issued for 30 days only and to extend it (which can be done only once), you have to go to the Kantor Imagrasi (immigration office) three times, and if you don't know the language, you would probably need a local agent to help you with the process. Since OP wants to stay 6 weeks, I'd definitely go for e-VOA.

@Axel You definitely don't need a local agent, but you do probably need around 1 to 2 weeks just to get the extension in a city with a Kantor Imagrasi, so you 'lose' 2 out of your 8.5 weeks... which might be fine or suck depending on where you plan to be your third and fourth week.

@DavidMulder I usually need three times at most two hours (first apply, second take biometric data, third get the passport) in Jogja, it's not like you can't do anything during that time, you are just not allowed to leave the province before they return your passport. If you intend to stay in a place rather far away from the kantor imigrasi, the bolak-balik can be annoying of course. Most foreigners I see at the imigrasi either have an agent or someone local who helps them filling out the form, but yes, it is not really required and the people are friendly there.

@Axel Yeah, I was very much putting the 'lose' between quotes, as of course you don't really loose it, but we wouldn't have spend that much time there otherwise. We didn't know when we had to be at the Kantor, but we did know it would take 1 to 2 weeks, so we just 'had to' book a hotel for 2 weeks which meant we had to get to Jogja earlier than planned, and stay there for longer.

Ah, yes, that's of course different. I stay at Jogja anyway for much longer, and the kantor imigrasi is maybe 30 minutes away from our house,  so it's no big deal for me. But I probably will get a Kitas (some sort of ID for foreigners in Indonesia that comes with a permanent stay permit) this year, so hopefully visa extensions are a thing of the past for me.

I've had so many issues with the online system; from it persisting incorrect details despite multiple times attempting to edit and save the correct details, such as:

my passport date always being continuously saved as the current date which caused it to be invalid and unlinked; rejected on arrival, had to pay for a new visa on arrival
to visas expiring before I arrive; rejected on arrival, had to pay for a new visa on arrival
to spending a day or more getting a photo that it actually accepts
to failed form inputs, failed page loads, web console filled with error messages, and so on

I've emailed them multiple times with the bugs, but I never get a response back. If you can use the visa-on-arrival do that, as it is far easier, and unfortunately, cheaper and quicker because of the current unreliability of the e-visa system.
The requirements are correct though, unlike the Holiday, Family, and Transit Single-Entry Visitor Visa (C1) visa, the Social Activities Single-Entry Visitor Visa (C6): seems the replacement of the old Social Cultural / Sosial Budaya Visa and Working and Holiday Temporary-Stay Visa for Australian (E35A) visas and others needs a guarantor letter, which the current online system does not support uploading; to do those ones you have to visit an Indonesian Embassy in-person, preferably with your Indonesian guarantor, who will be given a template that the guarantor must fill out and sign - if no template, it is a "you are a honourable and decent person, etc, etc" letter, accompanied with the guarantor's Indonesian identifiers.
Return flights from Malaysia (Indonesia's most popular visitor) go for $100-200, and return flights from Perth, Western Australia to Indonesia (Australians are Indonesia's second most popular visitor) go for $300AUD (200USD). So, yeah, they don't care about flight costs. However, even if the flight costed $100,000 it is still irrelevant of the purpose of the finance check. Which is to ensure you have a steady base level of finances in the event of an issue or determination, such that you aren't going to end up homeless in Indonesia and unable to return home. There are people, especially those seeking to avoid homeland conflicts, who have gone to Indonesia with no intent on returning.

"my passport date always being continuously saved as the current date" - saw that bug too! The whole website seems coded by a bunch of teenagers, excited to add three exclamation points at the end of each error message.
Given the number of visa intermediaries (who can also get a guarantor letter for you), I'd be surprised if there weren't any kickbacks and bribes involved to keep the current system as broken as it is.
